# Yup typescript number validation not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

I added react hook form in react app, while validating certain fields i add some condition in schema.

```
yup
  .object({
    test1: yup.number().when('test2', (test2: number, schema: yup.NumberSchema): yup.NumberSchema => {
      if (test2 !== undefined && test2 < 1) {
        return schema.required('Required Field').min(0).max(100).typeError('Please enter test1')
      }
      return schema.notRequired()
    }),
    Name: yup
      .string()
      .trim()
      .required('Required Field')
      .matches(/^[A-Za-z ]+$/, 'Numbers & Special character not allowed'),
    test2: yup.number().required('Required Field').min(0).max(100).typeError('Please enter test2'),
  })
  .required(
```

)

**TS2322: Type 'NumberSchema<Maybe<number | undefined>, AnyObject, undefined, "">' is not assignable to type 'NumberSchema<number | undefined, AnyObject, undefined, "">'.
Type 'Maybe<number | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.**

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log` `test2`, you'll see your issue - it's an array, not a number.

You also don't need to explicitly declare the types because they are correctly inferred. Try this:

```
    test1: yup.number().when('test2', ([test2],schema) => {
        ....
    }),
```

Notice `[test2]` instead of `test2`

See [this relevant part of the documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/README.md?plain=1#L1103-L1109):

```
let schema = yup.object({
  isBig: yup.boolean(),
  count: yup.number().when('isBig', ([isBig], schema) => {
    return isBig ? schema.min(5) : schema.min(0);
  }),
});
```